# associated fields not loading values from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to get a nested attributes form to detect the values already loaded into the database, can anyone see what is wrong with this code

controller

```
def edit
    @merchant = Merchant.find(params[:id])
    @states = State.form_selector
    @merchant.build_address if @merchant.address1.nil?
    @merchant.build_account if @merchant.bsb.nil?
    @products = Product.all
  end
```

view

```
= form.fields_for :address do |address_fields|
    = address_fields.hidden_field :address_type_id, value: 4
    = address_fields.hidden_field :default, value: true
    .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--12-col
      = address_fields.text_field :address1, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
      = address_fields.label :address1, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
    .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--12-col
      = address_fields.text_field :address2, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
      = address_fields.label :address2, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
    .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--6-col
      = address_fields.text_field :city, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
      = address_fields.label :city, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
    .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--2-col
      = address_fields.text_field :zip_code, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', :pattern => '^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$'
      = address_fields.label :zip_code, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
      %span.mdl-textfield__error= t('.postcode_error')
    .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--3-col
      = address_fields.select   :state_id, @states, :include_blank => true
      = address_fields.label :state_id, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
```

Comment: do you have the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` in your Merchant model?

Comment: yes the data gets committed to the database, but when you go to edit that element its like nothing had ever being saved

Comment: But is it called address1 or address? You are confusing them I guess: `@merchant.build_address if @merchant.address1.nil?`

Comment: the field is address1, the model is address

Answer (score 0):

`@merchant.address` return a collection and even if null it returned a array.

```
@merchant.address # []   
@merchant.address.nil?   # false
@merchant.address.blank? # true

def edit
  @merchant = Merchant.find(params[:id])
  @states = State.form_selecto
  @merchant.build_address if @merchant.address.blank?
  @merchant.build_account if @merchant.bsb.blank?
  @products = Product.all
end
```

But I prefer to use that way in the view. Because this way you remove a lot code of your controller actions #edit #new #update #create

```
view
- form.object.build_address if form.object.blank?
= form.fields_for :address do |address_fields|
    = address_fields.hidden_field :address_type_id, value: 4
```

Comment: using .blank still nets me the same result

Comment: this is whats in the model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['address1'].blank? }`

Comment: I would like see the has_many associations. In your rails console if you type this `Merchant.find(1).address` what is the return?

Comment: I want identify if your problem is in the model, controller or view

Comment: `Merchant.find(45).address
  Merchant Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE "merchants"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 45]]
  Address Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["addressable_id", 45], ["addressable_type", "Merchant"]]
=> #<Address:0x007ffa04a4ba18
 id: 4,
 address_type_id: 4,
 first_name: "Paul",
 last_name: "McGuane",
 addressable_type: "Merchant",
 addressable_id: 45,
 address1: "123 Fake",
 address2: "",
 city: "Test",`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120956/discussion-between-breno-perucchi-and-paul-whippet-mcguane).